# How to get border in fieldset tag in HTML

Tags: html

I'm using this HTML code but I'm not getting a border in `<feilset>`. Please, can any one help me to get this code working correctly?

```
<feildset>
    <label>PIS</label>
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-7">
            <label class="label_text">Tipo Cálculo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option>1 - Saida</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-7">
            <label class="label_text">Aliquota ICMS</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-7">
            <label class="label_text">Aliquota </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
        </div>
    </div>
</feildset>
```

Comment: First of all, it should be `<fieldset>`. And where is your CSS?

Comment: If should be `<fieldset>` not `<feildset>`

Answer (score 1):

The Error in your code is the typo mistake of `<feilset>` change it to  `<fieldset>`

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
     <legend>Sample</legend>
    <label>PIS</label>
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-7">
            <label class="label_text">Tipo Cálculo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5">
            <select class="form-control input-sm">
                <option>1 - Saida</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-7">
            <label class="label_text">Aliquota ICMS</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-3 col-sm-7">
            <label class="label_text">Aliquota </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kG9QL/4/)

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error.

```
<feildset> - wrong
<fieldset> - right
```

Comment: its not syntax error, it just a typo

Comment: English is not my preferred language. May be not error, but wrong "text". Don't know how say correct.

Comment: STILL  NOT GETTING BORDER

Comment: **<fieldset style="border: 1px;">** no?

Comment: @user3296899 have you checked my answer??

Comment: actully iam using fielset with proper tag bt the output is not shown the top border of feilset